Access response body in middleware unit test
I have a .net middleware that modifies the response and I'm trying to unit test it. I am able to successfully assert the status code and content type are correct, but when I attempt to assert the response body, it is an empty string even though a response body has been set.
I had no issues modifying or asserting the request body in another test. Is it possible to do the same for the response body?
Middleware:
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Web.API.Middleware
{
    public class SampleMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public SampleMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            bool success = true;

            // do other stuff which has been removed...

            context.Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain;
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Bad request"); // setting response body here

            success = false;

            if (success)
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
        }
    }
}

Unit test:
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;
using Web.API.Middleware;

namespace Web.API.UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class SampleMiddlewareTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task BadRequestTest()
        {
            // Arrange
            var expected = "Bad request";

            var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
            var nextMock = new Mock<RequestDelegate>();
            var middleware = new SampleMiddleware(nextMock.Object);

            // Act
            await middleware.InvokeAsync(httpContext);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, httpContext.Response.StatusCode); // works
            Assert.AreEqual(MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain, httpContext.Response.ContentType); // works

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpContext.Response.Body);
            var responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, responseBody); // fails
        }
    }
}

Test result:
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<Bad request>. Actual:<>. 


You should change the code in your unit test file:
1. Set the HttpContext.Response.Body to a new MemoryStream()
httpContext.Response.Body = new MemoryStream();
This allows you to manipulate or inspect the response content before sending it out, such as reading the content, modifying it, or analyzing it.
2. Reset the read position of the memory stream back to the beginning
httpContext.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
After writing the response content into it, the read position typically ends up at the end of the memory stream. So you should reset the read position of the memory stream back to the beginning. This allows you to reread the response content from the beginning.
The working code:
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task BadRequestTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var expected = "Bad request";

        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
        var nextMock = new Mock<RequestDelegate>();
        var middleware = new SampleMiddleware(nextMock.Object);

        // Set the HttpContext.Response.Body to a new MemoryStream()
        httpContext.Response.Body = new MemoryStream();

        // Act
        await middleware.InvokeAsync(httpContext);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, httpContext.Response.StatusCode); 
        Assert.AreEqual(MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain, httpContext.Response.ContentType); 

        // Reset the read position of the memory stream back to the beginning
        httpContext.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpContext.Response.Body);
        var responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, responseBody); 
    }
}

The Test Result:


